# React-native test fail

Tags: android, ubuntu, testing, react-native

I have followed all the steps for installing the react-native with andriod studio and everything runs smoothly, I have created a new project to run the react-native test but when the welcome message should come out the emulator screen stays in White, I show the screens so that what is happening is observed

I hope your answers thank you very much !!
Carga en el emulador 1 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFTDB.png]
Emulator 2 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzRtI.png]

Comment: try clean-->Build-->run again, or close application and start it again Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still have the same problem and tried to run in different KWD

Comment: Many thanks, I already found a solution, which was to run in a terminal react-native start, and in another terminal react-native run-andriod, and it worked. !!! Attached image if you can serve someone https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-aB7HSSGCgt8/WSeKyu32zpI/AAAAAAAAIcM/-BfulvWCbLMod7DcwFWa2vbUWcSajcddwCL0B/h1024/final.png